# run js on html element dynamically with Django(template)

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to run `price_update()` function on h6 element

```
{% for products in allProducts %}
<div class="col-6"> 
    Final Price: <h6 id="final_price_{{product.slug}}" onload="price_update({{products.price}},{{products.offer}}, {{product.slug}})"></h6>                                    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function price_update(price, offer, slug) {
    let discounted_price = price- parseInt(price * offer / 100);
    let id = "final_price_" + String(slug);
    let f_price = document.getElementById(id);
    f_price.innerText = discounted_price;                                   
}
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

I got to know that `onload` cannot be used with `<h6>` .
How can update innerText of `<h6>` for every product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters), do the arithmetic calculations there and, get the result :

- In one of your apps create a new folder that is named `templatetags`
- paste in the folder the  `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.
- In `templatetags` folder, create a new module. This module is the one that would be loaded in your template. something like : `myapp_extras.py`
- Import desired models `(product)` and then, add `register = template.Library()` to ensure the the module is a valid tag library
- Register the custom filter by:

register the filter

```
@register.filter(name='price_update')
def price_update(product_id):
    # Get the product by id, and calculate the price
    
    # Return updated price
```

Load the module `{% load myapp_extras %}` in the template then, in your template use `price_update` tag:

```
<div class="col-6"> 
    Final Price: <h6 id="final_price_{{product.slug}}" >{{product.id|price_pudate}}</h6>                                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63391216/14020019 by *Amin Mir* absolutely correct but I've implemented the solution in different way.
2. **My Solution** :
   I've added property in my model

   ```
   @property
   def final_price(self):
       f_price = self.price - (self.price * self.offer // 100)
       return f_price
   ```

   using this I directly used the *final_price* using `.` operator, i.e. `product.final_price`